# Dataweave error Cannot coerce a :number to a :array

Tags: mule, mule-component, dataweave

I have a situation in which I need to update a field SFDC object from a variable, when doing this i receive an error "Cannot coerce a :number to a :array"  my dataweave script it like

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload map
{
    Id: flowVars.ABC_ID,
    EPPICORE_Id__c: flowVars.HTTP_return_id
}
```

when I remove payload map from this it throws an error that it should be collection or object, Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: Add more context, the sample input would be usefull.

Comment: Are you actually trying to coerce a number into an array?

Comment: I just wanted to push the value stored in a variable to a field in salesforce (update). In data weave I see list<Object> at the output due to Salesforce. Where as i am getting a string payload in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the payload in debug. 
Dataweave recognizes three canonical structures and some mule variables and structures.
1)lists of items(numerics,strings)  or lists[objects] see #2
2)objects (say one big XML or JSON)
3)String(s)
4)Mule variables (can hold almost anything)
If you have a list of objects as input in your payload and you are using the dataweave payload map (without the $) statement which  breaks out each of the occurrences of your list each yielding an object per iteration as you loop thru the list in the payload.
What you have written would seem to want to loop thru your payload input
and build associative array-looking output using the same output values in ABC_ID and HTTP_return_id for each iteration of the list in payload. 
Is your payload input a single item list? if not, then it seems hard to understand what you are seeking because you seek to iterate thru the payload...
If so, perhaps you should change the output to text and simply output your flowvars values as a single string text entity with the flowvars values inserted. But Mauro Rocco is right - more info on your input is needed! Cheers!